# Creating a standalone (executable) from mathematica code

Tags: compile, excel, code-generation

I have written a small mathematica code to input a ".csv" file and output the data in a specific format, in a ".txt" file. I would like to give this program as an executable to my friend as she doesn't have mathematica installed. I've seen how one creates ".exe" from mathematica. However the process doesn't seem to work for me. Can anyone kindly help. Here is the mathematica code:

```
content=Drop[Transpose[Import["~/Downloads/19162.csv"]],2];

sorted=GatherBy[DeleteCases[DeleteCases[Flatten[content],""],"="],StringTake[#,StringPosition[#,"="][[1]][[1]]]&];

tab=OutputForm[TableForm[sorted]];

Export["~/Downloads/19162.txt",tab]
```

I would like the executable to input a file (in ".csv") format and output the text file in the "~/Downloads/" folder (of course the choice of the folder isn't important here).

Comment: Do you have an Enterprise Edition?

Comment: I'm afraid you are in for disappointment.  Apart from the Enterprise Edition or Wolfram Player Pro *Mathematica* does not have this feature, and even in those cases the distributable functionality is limited (I believe).

Comment: http://www.wolfram.com/player-pro/how-player-pro-compares.html

Comment: @PavithranIyer Import and Export functions cannot be compiled and written to C, so you are left with what can be done in the middle and writing something to do the bits on either side.

Comment: You could do this with wolfram engine + dockerized web server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not appear that this is possible without the Enterprise edition of *Mathematica* (or, perhaps, an alternative conclusion is that *Mathematica* is not the best tool for this job). As [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) points out:

> I'm afraid you are in for disappointment. Apart from the Enterprise Edition or Wolfram Player Pro Mathematica does not have this feature, and even in those cases the distributable functionality is limited.

[Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) provides a [link](http://www.wolfram.com/player-pro/how-player-pro-compares.html) to a chart showing a feature comparison between FreeCDF, Enterprise CDF, Player Pro, and *Mathematica*.

My suggestion would be to approach this problem in Python instead. It is easy to learn, not extremely dissimilar from *Mathematica* in overall style and (programming) functionality, and will not give you any problems with redistribution.

Comment: I've done the same with Python -- thanks, it was a good choice !