# Can a computer run a Mathematica program without Mathematica?

Tags: notebooks, cdfplayer

I wrote a Mathematica program on my computer using my licensed copy of Mathematica. Can someone who does not have a licensed copy of Mathematica run my program?

Comment: In most cases, probably not. Take a look at the discussion in this question: [Creating a standalone (executable) from mathematica code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39169/27951), of which yours may be a duplicate.

Comment: There's https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/online/, based on http://www.wolfram.com/cloud/.  I've never used it, so I don't know whether it will do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The [CDF player](https://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/) is available from Wolfram.
It can run CDF files which you can create from any Mathematica notebook by using File->CDF export->Standalone.

Comment: I downloaded CDF player, then opened my notebook and did File->CDF export->Standalone. Then I open the CDF file with the CDF player. When I try to run it, it says "You are running in a mode which does not allow computations..."???

Comment: In general, CDF Player Pro is needed to run Mathematica files created with File->CDF export->Standalone. The other option is to upgrade to Mathematica Enterprise, which creates .cdf files that can run on the free CDF Player.