# How to create standalone applications?

Tags: export, import, data, cdf-format

I have to create a standalone application with Mathematica, but I'm asking if it's possible to create an application that reads (or import) data from different .xlsx (or .csv) sheets, so I have to specify the pathname of the file, and then gives back different plots, results of data analysis, etc... that can even be exported and saved.

If it's possible, where I can find some tutorials and similar worked examples?

I apologize for the trivial question..

Comment: By "standalone" do you mean "works on a PC without a Mathematica license installed"? AFAIK, this isn't possible.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39169/131. Searching the site for "standalone" should have brought that up, amongst others.

Comment: @nikie : Thanks for your comments. However yes... I was supposing like that, through the CDF.

Comment: @ Yves Klett, Thaks, I  saw it, but it was asked quite 3 years ago, so I thought that maybe there was something new now