# Is it possible when creating an exe file from Mathematica code to include functions that create windows?

Tags: programming, sql

I'm building a program that uses SQL code to import live data, and uses said data to calculate basic SPC limits. This data is then graphed in a separate window. My final goal is to be able to turn this program into an executable that other people at my company can use, but I'd like to know if the features I've described are something I can incorporate before I pursue the .exe path. I'm certainly willing to consider other alternatives such as the CDF player (even if it is the Enterprise Edition).

For clarity's sake, my program works by the following flowchart as of right now:

1) Upon evaluating, a GUI is created which has a button to open the Connection Wizard.

2) When the user selects the desired database, they select the appropriate table and column as well as the number of samples, and then selects a button that creates a new notebook window with the graph of the data.

3) Within this notebook, there are scheduled tasks to continually query the data for updating. No actual queries are done outside of this notebook.

4) Multiple created notebooks can be open at a time, and they all update independently of each other. The user just has to change the table and column specifications and hit the create window button again.

Also, I am aware that a lot of step 2 is redundant with the database explorer, but I had troubles with using it and this method does work within Mathematica.

Comment: You can't create .exe files in MMA, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39169/5478. Was that the question?

Comment: It certainly answers it. Thank you.